# Multiple mappings per ActiveModel/Record?

Tags: autocomplete, elasticsearch, tire, n-gram

Lets say I want to create two separate indexes on something like BlogPosts, so that I can do a quick search using one index (for autocomplete purposes for example) then use the other index for full blown search querying.

Is that something I can do with Tire?
so something like this (forgive me if its a little primitive)

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

   index_name 'autocomplete'
  mapping do
      indexes :title, :analyzer => 'my_ngram_analyzer'
  end

  index_name 'main'
  mapping do 
      indexes :title
      indexes :description
      indexes :author
      indexes :published_on
  end
end
```

where the callbacks know to add and remove new posts from the appropriate indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in Tire, setting two separate indices (and mappings) in one class with the `mapping` DSL method.

It may be a good idea to use two separate indices, one for auto-completion, another for search. There's a nice [tutorial](http://jprante.github.com/applications/2012/08/17/Autocompletion-with-jQuery-JAX-RS-and-Elasticsearch.html), StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421358/filename-search-with-elasticsearch/9432450#9432450) and even an elasticsearch [plugin](https://github.com/spinscale/elasticsearch-suggest-plugin) to get you started.

However, unless you have a lot of data, you'd be able to achieve that even with a single index, using the `multi_field` type, `match` query across multiple fields, and potentially an NGram based analyzer.

Check out the [**Autocomplete with Tire**](https://github.com/spinscale/elasticsearch-suggest-plugin) tutorial which outlines the approach.

---

Cross-post from https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/531

Comment: Thank you Karmi, I left a note on the issues page for Tire as well.