# multiple like query in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a field `path` in my elastic-search documents which has entries like this

```
/logs/hadoop-yarn/container/application_1451299305289_0120/container_e18_1451299305289_0120_01_011007/stderr
/logs/hadoop-yarn/container/application_1451299305289_0120/container_e18_1451299305289_0120_01_008874/stderr

#*Note -- I want to select all the documents having below line in the **path** field
/logs/hadoop-yarn/container/application_1451299305289_0120/container_e18_1451299305289_0120_01_009257/stderr
```

I want to make a like query on this `path` field given certain things(basically an AND condition on all the 3):-

1. I have given application number `1451299305289_0120`
2. I have also given a task number `009257`
3. The path field should also contain `stderr`

Given the above criteria the document having the path field as the 3rd line should be selected

This is what I have tries so far

```
http://localhost:9200/logstash-*/_search?q=application_1451299305289_0120 AND path:stderr&size=50
```

This query fulfills the 3rd criteria, and partially the 1st criteria i.e if I search for `1451299305289_0120` instead of `application_1451299305289_0120`, I got 0 results. (What I really need is like search on `1451299305289_0120`)

When I tried this

```
http://10.30.145.160:9200/logstash-*/_search?q=path:*_1451299305289_0120*008779 AND path:stderr&size=50
```

I got the result, but using `*` at the start is a costly operation. Is their another way to achieve this effectively (like using `nGram` and using `fuzzy-search` of `elastic-search`)

Comment: Using nGram will very costly however what you can do edgeNGram use a couple of filters while analyzing..

I suggest you can look into this article..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421358/filename-search-with-elasticsearch#

It may be of little help, as in you can get some direction..

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using [Pattern Replace Char Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html). You just extract only important bits of information with `regex`. This is my setup

```
POST log_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "app_analyzer": {
          "char_filter": [
            "app_extractor"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        },
        "path_analyzer": {
          "char_filter": [
            "path_extractor"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        },
        "task_analyzer": {
          "char_filter": [
            "task_extractor"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "app_extractor": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": ".*application_(.*)/container.*",
          "replacement": "$1"
        },
        "path_extractor": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": ".*/(.*)",
          "replacement": "$1"
        },
        "task_extractor": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": ".*container.{27}(.*)/.*",
          "replacement": "$1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "your_type": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "application_number": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "app_analyzer"
            },
            "path": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "path_analyzer"
            },
            "task": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "task_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am extracting `application number`, `task number` and `path` with regex. You might want to optimize `task regex` a bit if you have some other log pattern, then we can use [Filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-filters.html) to search.A big advantage of using filters is that they are **cached** and make subsequent calls faster.

I indexed sample log like this

```
PUT log_index/your_type/1
{
  "name" : "/logs/hadoop-yarn/container/application_1451299305289_0120/container_e18_1451299305289_0120_01_009257/stderr"
}
```

This query will give you desired results

```
GET log_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "name.application_number": "1451299305289_0120"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "name.task": "009257"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "name.path": "stderr"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

On a side note `filtered query` is deprecated in `ES 2.x`, just use filter directly.Also [path hierarchy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html?q=hie) might be useful for some other uses

Hope this helps :)