# how to do full text search in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have very big data in on table (more then 4lc rows). Right now i am using mysql full text search but its very slow.

I google and found many blog which suggest to use elastic search for searching.
We are testing if elastic search will help in fast search.

but we are getting opposite result(mysql better search), but i doubt if i have used elastic search in correct way. Elastic search query i used is:-

```
{
 "query" : {
     "bool" : {
        "must" : {
           "query_string" : {
               "query" : "goog*",
               "default_field" : "search"
           }
        }
     }
 },
 "size" : 1000
}
```

For same search in mysql we used

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM table1 WHERE (MATCH (search) AGAINST (' +goog*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

I get time diff:-
elastic time = `0.34929585456848`

mysql time = `0.02162504196167`

Any suggestion where i am wrong I will very much appreciate

Comment: @NimChimpsky approx 4 lac

Comment: what does 4 lac  mean ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky means around 400000 rows

Comment: thats not really big enough to get benefit of elastic search, I would stick with mysql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first reason for query being a little slow is because you are using wildcard while searching...

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/search-in-depth.html

I will suggest that you look into elastic search mapping, analyzers to get the benefit of elastic search you will need to index your data correctly, and apply the right set of queries...

[Filename search with ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421358/filename-search-with-elasticsearch#)

this is a little advanced example to just show how to achieve search in between words of a file..

How your data is indexed can also effect the search query timing, and the query itself which you will be using..

You can register here and look into a short video on the different type of queries provided by elastic guys only..

https://www.elastic.co/webinars/elasticsearch-query-dsl

You can't decide which one is better without proper analysis..that too in elastic-search where indexing of the data effects a lot..

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36457568/full-text-searching-elasticticsearch 
@anirudh