# full text searching elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use elasticsearch over mysql for my full text searching (current it is slow), so i am just making demo and i am finding mysql performing better.

But i doubt if i am do something wrong

Till now what i have done:-

**localhost:9200/elastic_analysis_pattern/_settings**

```
{
  "elastic_analysis_pattern": {
  "settings": {
     "index": {
       "creation_date": "1459959233955",
       "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "edge_ngram": {
               "min_gram": "2",
               "side": "front",
               "type":  "edgeNGram",localhost:9200/elastic_analysis_pattern/_mapping/
              "max_gram": "20"
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
             "pattern_index": {
                 "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "stop",
                    "edge_ngram"
                  ],
                "tokenizer": "pattern_token"
             },
             "pattern_search": {
                 "filter": [
                   "lowercase",
                   "stop"
                  ],
                "tokenizer": "whitespace_token"
             }
         },
        "tokenizer": {
            "whitespace_token": {
                "type": "whitespace"
             },
           "pattern_token": {
                "pattern": "[^\\p{L}\\d]+",
                "type": "pattern"
            }
         }
      },
      "number_of_shards": "5",
      "number_of_replicas": "1",
      "uuid": "109pq9KfTVq32rIydKMPtg",
      "version": {
         "created": "2020199"
       }
    }
 }
 }
}
```

**localhost:9200/elastic_analysis_pattern/_mapping/**

```
{
  "elastic_analysis_pattern": {
  "mappings": {
    "search_analysis": {
       "properties": {
          "search": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "pattern_index",
            "search_analyzer": "pattern_search"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
}
```

query i am searching is say:-

```
{
   "query" : {
          "bool" : {
                    "must"  : {
                        "query_string"  : {
                            "query" : "sho",
                            "default_field"    => "search"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "size"  => 10
   }
```

and mysql query is:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM internet_ads WHERE (MATCH (search) AGAINST (' +sho*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) LIMIT 0,10
```

i am testing with database having around 60,000 row

**exectution time is**

**elastic time** = `0.034985065460205`
**mysql time** = `0.01869797706604`

Can anyone please let me know if i am doing something wrong here.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: How many ES nodes do you have? Regarding the row count, I'd use only one shard.

Comment: @MichaelStockerl one node

Comment: @MichaelStockerl For testing purpose i dumped only 50000 row but in real i have around 400000 and it will keep growing. I am not very sure how to decide how many shard should i create. Can you explain. 
i am very new with ES and started ES last week only

Comment: Okay. However, 400000 is also not too much for a lucene index. Still, I would suggest to try with 1 primary shard and 0 replica. Especially, as you have only 1 node, the replica cannot be allocated... Moreover, when you want to do full text search, the sorting may look broken, if you use two many shards.

Comment: @MichaelStockerl ok thanks i will make that change and will see if get any improvement

Comment: Is the number of records being fetched same in elastic and sql?

You must understand that in elastic the size parameter is limit the number of result which will be returned in the response, it might be returning 10 results, but beneath it you might have got more than 10 results..

Also can you once see the performance by replacing query string query with match query?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

here is how you can use it..

Comment: @AnirudhModi changed query to use match but no luck. 
how can i check if i am getting more then 10 results?

I was thinking do number of rows matter? does it make sense?

Comment: @MichaelStockerl used only 1 shards.

I was thinking do number of rows matter? does it make sense?

Comment: used only 1 shards but no luck

Comment: when you get the search results there will be field named total.. which specifices the number of rows it matched.. that can tell if their is any difference..

Comment: @AnirudhModi thanks man.. you saved my time (total was showing all resultset)... ES by default do relevance search while in my mysql query i was doing normal FTsearch. that is why ES was taking more time than Mysql.
Now ES showing better result.