# Create all possible tokens in order in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

I am trying to create an analyzer which can return all possible tokens, for example for this word `AB-12-1993 xyz.pdf` the tokens generated would be `AB, AB-12, -12-1993, 12-1993, -1993, 1993, AB-12-1993 xyz, xyz, xyz.pdf, AB-12-1993 xyz.pdf`, if any other extra token is generated that is not an issue. But these should be generated.

I have tried with whitespace analyzer with ngram but these `-12-1993, 12-1993, -1993, 1993` are not getting generated.

I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421358/filename-search-with-elasticsearch), with different analyzers but of no help

I am using elasticsearch 8.3.3. Can somebody please help me out here please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below definition for your analyzer which produces your required tokens

```
PUT ngram_custom_example
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "max_ngram_diff": 10
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [ "2_10_grams" ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "2_10_grams": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 10
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was using ngrams, but I forgot to update type to ngram from edge_ngram

Comment: @ShivamRaj, :) its ok, glad my answer helped you